# Matrix equation involving the Jordan product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $n\times n$ matrices $M$ and $N$, let $\mathcal{J}(M,N)=MN+NM$. Now suppose $A$ and $B$ are known square matrices with $A$ invertible. Then does the matrix equation $\mathcal{J}(A,X)=B$ always have a solution, and if so, is this solution unique? Moreover, if there is in fact a unique solution $X$, is there a formula for $X$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Please add [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution doesn't always exist, just like a solution doesn't exist for over/underdetermined linear systems. However, you can always calculate a least-squares solution in these cases.

A straightforward approach is to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the equation, solve the resulting linear system using a pseudoinverse, and then *de-vectorize* the result back into the shape of a matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\rs{\operatorname{reshape}}
\def\sz{\operatorname{size}}
X + \A XA = \A B \\
\left(I+A^T\otimes\A\right)\vc(X) = \vc(\A B) \\
\vc(X) = \left(I+A^T\otimes\A\right)^{+}\,\vc(\A B) \\
X = \rs\!\big(\vc(X),\;\sz(X)\,\big) \\
}$$
If your equation does have a solution, then this method will find it. If it does not have a solution, then this method is as close (norm-wise) as you're likely to get.

Also note that your equation is an instance of the [Sylvester Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). So if the eigenvalues of $(+A)$ do not overlap those of $(-A)$, then a specialized Sylvester algorithm will be much quicker than the above vectorization method.

Julia and Matlab have built-in solvers for such equations, and libraries routines are available for most other languages.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no reason for solutions to either exist or be unique. Take $n = 2$ and for simplicity take $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 \end{array} \right]$ to be diagonal. Then

$$J(A, X) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 x_{11} & a_1 x_{12} \\ a_2 x_{21} & a_2 a_{22} \end{array} \right] + \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 x_{11} & a_2 x_{12} \\ a_1 x_{21} & a_2 a_{22} \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 2a_1 x_{11} & (a_1 + a_2) x_{12} \\ (a_1 + a_2) x_{21} & 2a_2 a_{22} \end{array} \right] = B$$

so we see that if $a_1 = -a_2$ then the off-diagonal entries of $J(A, X)$ must be zero; if the off-diagonal entries of $B$ are nonzero then no solutions exist, and when they exist $x_{12}$ and $x_{21}$ are arbitrary so they aren't unique.